# How to convert a string representation of bytearray to a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, representation

I have a string like this:

```
string = "b'\\xf4\\xf0\\xf2\\xef\\xf8\\xf2\\xee'"
```

So far I have come up with this:

```
arr = np.array([int(s_num, 16) for s_num in re.findall(r'x([a-f0-9]{2})', string)], dtype=np.uint8)
```

For large strings this gets really slow. What is the best way to convert the string to a numpy array (of data type `np.uint8`)? Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't have that string to begin with, but rather `b'\\xf4\\xf0\\xf2\\xef\\xf8\\xf2\\xee'`. How did you get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
from ast import literal_eval

np.frombuffer(literal_eval(string), dtype=np.uint8)
```

output: `array([244, 240, 242, 239, 248, 242, 238], dtype=uint8)`